# @RestController @GetMapping No adapter for handler issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Learning Spring Rest, had some doubt on below:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/test")    
    public int testTransaction(){
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Above snippet worked very well, and returned response 10.

```
@RestController("/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @GetMapping 
    public int testTransaction(){
        return 10;
    }
}
```

For above snippet, getting me an error as below:

```
 threw exception No adapter for handler The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler with root cause
```

Any idea? what could be the reason..? I am thinking both should work, but above one is not working...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your second code piece you didn't specify request mapping for your controller.

This should be done in `@RequestMapping` not in `@RestController`.

This should work:

```java
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @GetMapping 
    public int testTransaction(){
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Your first code piece works because you specified request mapping on a method level - `@GetMapping("/test")`